# ¿Cómo obtener la penúltima fecha de modificación de un registro, en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo esta consulta en SQL-Server, y tengo un campo que se llama `data_ultcol`, que es la última fecha donde se hizo la modificación del registro; ahora, donde dice `dato` en la consulta, necesito que me traiga la penúltima fecha donde se modificó el registro.

```
select case ht.estagio when '0' then ht.DATA_PLANTIO else dato end as FECHA_COSECHA_ANTERIOR,
ht.data_ultcol as FECHA_ULTIMA_COSECHA,
ht.faz as Hacienda,
ht.tal as Suerte,
ht.area_p as Area,
(
        select  sum(ri.area_ri)
            from
                ri_irrig_tal ri,
                operagr op
            where
                ri.faz = ht.faz and
                ri.tal = ht.tal and
                ri.data between case ht.estagio when 0 then ht.data_plantio else dato end and  ht.data_ultcol and
                ri.oper = op.codigo and
                op.nome like 'RIEGO ASPERSION%'
) AREA_REGADA_ASPERCION,

(
         select  sum(ri.area_ri)
            from
                ri_irrig_tal ri,
                operagr op
            where
                ri.faz = ht.faz and
                ri.tal = ht.tal and
                ri.data between case ht.estagio when 0 then ht.data_plantio else dato  end and  ht.data_ultcol and
                ri.oper = op.codigo and
                op.nome like 'RIEGO GRAV%'
) AREA_REGADA_GRAVEDAD,

ht.ton_mol TONELADAS,
        
(
            select  sum(ri.m3)
            from
                ri_irrig_tal ri,
                operagr op
            where
                ri.faz = ht.faz and
                ri.tal = ht.tal and
                ri.data between case ht.estagio when 0 then ht.data_plantio else dato  end and  ht.data_ultcol and
                ri.oper = op.codigo and
                op.nome like 'RIEGO ASPERSION%'
) M3_AGUA_ASPERSION,

(
            select  sum(ri.m3)
            from
                ri_irrig_tal ri,
                operagr op
            where
                ri.faz = ht.faz and
                ri.tal = ht.tal and
                ri.data between case ht.estagio when 0 then ht.data_plantio else dato  end and  ht.data_ultcol and
                ri.oper = op.codigo and
                op.nome like 'RIEGO GRAV%'

) M3_AGUA_GRAVEDAD,

        ht.PROPRIEDADE as Tenencia

        from
        historia ht
where 
        ht.data_ultcol between convert(datetime, '20150101',106) and getdate()
order by
        ht.data_ultcol,
        ht.faz, 
        ht.tal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias hacer un subconsulta ultilizando `row_number()` que es una función de ventana que asigna un número entero secuencial a cada fila en el conjunto de resultados de la consulta.

```
  CREATE TABLE #fecha
(
fecha datetime,
idusuario int,
)

INSERT INTO #fecha VALUES (getdate(),1)
INSERT INTO #fecha VALUES (getdate()-1,1)
INSERT INTO #fecha VALUES (getdate()-2,2)
INSERT INTO #fecha VALUES (getdate()-3,3)
INSERT INTO #fecha VALUES (getdate()-4,3)
INSERT INTO #fecha VALUES (getdate()-5,3)
```

Como ya tienes una secuencia la ordenas `DESC` y lo filtras por la segunda posición que seria la penultima fecha en este caso.
Aqui en la subconsulta le mandas el id del usuario para obtener la penultima fecha por usuario. Tambien se hace un `count` de cuantos cambios ha hecho un usuario en caso que tenga solo uno trae la unica fecha pero si tiene mas de 1 trae la penultima.

```
 SELECT * fROM #fecha

SELECT fecha,idusuario FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS rn, fecha,idusuario,
(SELECT COUNT(idusuario) FROM #fecha WHERe idusuario = 2) AS conteo
FROM #fecha WHERE idusuario=2

) t1 
WHERE rn= CASE WHEN conteo >1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END


DROP table #fecha
```

y el resultado seria el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Jacobo gracias por responder, una pregunta se me olvido poner en la explicación que es para sacar la penúltima fecha de un histórico que tiene registros digamos por usuario, entonces seria para sacar la penúltima fecha de modificación por usuario, es para un reporte por usuarios, de la forma en que esta me saca la penúltima fecha pero de toda la tabla, muchas gracias por responder, si me pudieras ayudar estaría muy agradecido

Comment: Modifique la respuesta por lo que entiendo que necesitas, espero que te sirva.